# Power of attorney

Tags: lawyers

I wrote and submitted my software patent application by myself and got Alice rejection (not completely unexpected). I contacted a patent lawyer to write claim amendments and he sent me contract and power of attorney forms to sign. I am comfortable with going with him but if we get final action rejection I want to switch back and continue persecution on my own. I just think it wouldn't worth all lawyer's fees. My concern: how difficult it would be to  get my case back from the law firm and have POA reversed?

Comment: There seems to be a page on USPTO site but it requires registration number and I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be very easy. The simplest would be to simply ask your patent attorney to withdraw his power of attorney.

You can also just file form AIA/81. Sign the form without appointing anyone to prosecute the application. This will have the effect of withdrawing the existing PoA.